# Click listener in ViewHolder only sometimes responds

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have the following piece of code. Below you can see my viewholder, adapter and my xml. The problem I'm encountering is that the click is sometimes not executed. Only when I'm also set clicklisteners in my viewholder on the textview and imageview than it works. Presumably the click gets eaten by the textview and imageview. Anybody have any idea why this behaviour occurs.

```
class GeneralListItemViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

   var item: GeneralItemViewModel? = null

   init {
       view.setOnClickListener {
            item?.method?.invoke()
       }
   }

   fun bind(item: GeneralItemViewModel) {
      this.item = item
      //Do some nice UI things
   }
}
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/ListItem">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/general_list_item_icon"
    style="@style/ListItem.Icon"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/general_list_item_title"
    style="@style/ListItem.Labels.Title"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/general_list_item_icon" />
```

Furthermore my adapter code holds the following:

```
class GeneralItemAdapter(val items: List<GeneralItemViewModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GeneralListItemViewHolder>() {

   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GeneralListItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
       return holder.bind(getItem(position))
   }

   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GeneralListItemViewHolder {
       val view = parent.inflate(R.layout.general_list_item, false)
       return GeneralListItemViewHolder(view)
   }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
   }

   private fun getItem(position: Int): GeneralItemViewModel {
       return items[position]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the ClickListener in the bind method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue has to do with the use of synthetic kotlin extension on the view. If you use them on the variable view instead of itemView then the click gets eaten by the textview.

```
fun bind(item: AboutGeneralItemViewModel) {
    this.item = item

    itemView.general_list_item_title.text = item.value
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        item?.method?.invoke()
    }
}
```